# Rendering a template and invoking model hook in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am using JSON requests to populate the model for a template called example.

```
App.ExampleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var url = "example/GetExamples";
    return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
      return data;
    });
  }
});
```

The example template perfectly renders this data. Now my backend might change from time to time as I have another template called addExample. It just sends a JSON request to the server to add an entry in the database from this other template. After adding the examples, I try to transition to example template but I see old data only. On refreshing the page, the new data with the added entry comes up.

```
App.AddController=Ember.Controller.extend({
  postAddRequest: function() {
    var request = $.post("/example/AddExample", {params});
    request.then(this.success.bind(this), this.failure.bind(this));
  },
  success: function(data) {
    this.transitionToRoute('example');
  }
});
```

So is there any way I can force Ember to re render 'example' template and invoke its model hook in the route without refreshing the page. I can't use ember-data for persistence as it is still in beta stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transition to the route and send the data you'd like to use on the route.  Additionally the route should be using an id/slug in the url.  If not see below

```
this.transitionToRoute('example', data);
```

If you are already on the route and you want to update the model of a currently set controller you can grab that controller and set the model.

#### From the controller

```
App.SomeController = Em.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['example']
  someFunction: function(){
    var model = ... get new model;
    this.get('controllers.example').set('model', model);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for amswering. Just a couple of clarifications, what do you mean by Additionally the route should be using an id/slug in the url? Also for the second example, is this only valid when I am on the same route? That means I should be on ExampleRoute to accomplish this?? Can't I get the controller for a template from a diferent route? Sorry I am an ember newbie

Comment: The second method you suggested works, I am able to set new model from the same route but I am still not able to do it from a different route.

Comment: I'm not completely following, can you explain it to me using an example, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/189/edit ?

Comment: Hi, I have added a new template called change which would try to change the colors model on click of a button. I am trying to add new model from a variable called newColors. Also I am not using ember data so store wouldn't come into picture. The link is http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/190/edit

Comment: so in your example, the `colors` resource isn't even active, will it be active when you try and modify it?

Comment: Ya I forgot to mention, after  this.controllerFor('colors').set('model', newColors); I do transitionToRoute('colors');

Comment: whoops, sorry, I missed responding here, if your route doesn't have a dynamic slug (:id, :myrecordid etc) in the map, you are essentially saying the model is a static model (aka always the same) so the 'model' hook of that route is where the logic should live that grabs the records for that route.  Since there is no dynamic slug you can't tell ember to use a particular model for that route until you've transitioned to that route.

Comment: So if you wanted you could transition to the route, then change the model.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/194/edit