# Ember: Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [object Object]

Tags: ember.js

I get this error:

> Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [object Object]

When I run the following code:

```
setContent: function() {
  try {
    return this.set('content', JSON.parse(sessionStorage.userData));
  } catch(e) {}
}.on('init')
```

and this HBS bit:

```
{{#each options}}
  <li>{{@key}}: {{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

This question seemed unrelated to my issue: [Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691927/assertion-failed-the-value-that-each-loops-over-must-be-an-array-you-passed)

EDIT: 
`userData` is an object with an array and an object in. Before `{{#each options}}` is called the context is set inside one of the arrays.

The odd part is that this bit of code has the same data elsewhere outside my Ember app and runs through the same HBS `each`. It works fine there but not in the app.

Comment: What's `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.userData)`?  And what's `options`? You can't iterate an object, it needs to be an array...

Comment: sorry, I'll update the question with a bit more info